# How to introduce linebreak in plotly axislabels while using latex encodings?

Tags: python, latex, plotly, line-breaks, axis-labels

I want to have a 2 line ticktext in my plotly diagram and have to rely on latex encoding for some other functionality.
It seems that in this particular case neither the html encoding

```
<br>
```

nor the latex

```
\linebreak
\newline
\\
```

seem to work when added in that string (the html is simply ignored, the latex is added as symbols in the text).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=range(10),ticktext=['$'+str(x)+'\linebreak \color{green}{A}$' for x,y in enumerate(range(10))])#$\color{green}{A}}$
fig.show()
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Would you be so kind and share a minimal reproducable example!

Answer (score 0):

The html is simply ignored? Sounds like there's an input error somewhere. For a simple linebreak, there's no need to unleash Latex. The following example sets up the x-ticks as the x-values and x**2 separated by two linebreaks.
This at least works on my end.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))

t1=x.tolist()

x1=x**2
t2=x1.tolist()

z=['<br><br>'.join(map(str, i)) for i in zip(t1, t2)]

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=x,ticktext=z)
fig.show()
```

This will work for any two lists where you'd like a linebreak between each corresponding element of those lists.

Comment: That's true, I know. But I need the latex functionality as well; and that was actually when the error started occurring. Before I was also fine sticking with html